# Storing a large list of files for an asset in noSQL db (firestore)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a document which looks like:

```
{
  name: "Some Name",
  description: "Some Description",
  files: [
    { name: 'filename1', type: 0 },
    { name: 'filename2', type: 2 },
    { name: 'filename3', type: 1 },
    // Many many more ~10k
  ]
```

The problem is that the `files` array can get into thousands. A few of my tests have been around 6-10k objects in that array.

Firestore has a 1mb file limit which could be a factor but I also need to think about searching on that data by any of the fields.

How would I best store this information in a noSQL environment? In a SQL world, I'd have a separate table with a row per file. Should I just have a document per files in a `files` collection and have an asset id against each file to link them? Seems very relational for a non relational DB that way but I also worry about the cost of reading "per document" (although, they won't ALL be read at once, it'd be searchable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There rarely is a "one and unique" perfect solution when designing NoSQL data models. One classical key criteria is to look at the queries that will be executed and work out the model in order to optimize the queries (e.g. denormalizing data in such a way we can get the desired data in one query only).

Having said that, since you explain that:

- A document may reach the 1mb limit, due to the size of the `files` field;
- If you create a collection of `files`, "they won't ALL be read at once, it'd be searchable"

I would suggest you use a subcollection for each "asset" (i.e. the entity holding the `name` and `description` fields)

Since **you will only search this subcollection**, you will only pay for reading the documents corresponding to the query, not for reading the entire collection.

Using a subcollection automatically materializes the `asset`/`file` link.

---

Other advantages we may think of with this data model:

- It facilitates concurrent updates of the `files` list;
- If, in your app/front-end, you first query for an `asset` and then query for some `files`, the performance will be better, compare to querying a "whole" `asset` containing the entire `files` list.

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thank you. One question, with the sub collection approach, will I have any issues searching "all" the sub collections? Basically, I'll have multiple assets which might contain a file with "tree" in the name - I'll need to bring back all those files along with their parent asset.

Comment: You can use a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query across the subcollections. Note that you must create an index that supports your collection group query, so if you have a massive number of `file` records it may be better to have a unique root collection that contains all the `file` records, each one having a filed containing the ID of the parent `asset` doc (mimicking a foreign key), as you mentioned in your question. (to be cont...)

Comment: ... In terms of query cost it doesn't make any difference, since the cost of a query is function of the size of the result (one read per document returned, unless there isn't any result, in which case it costs one read). PS: I'd suggest you watch this official video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2 (as well as the entire "Get to know Cloud Firestore" series btw! ;-))

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This is all really helpful.
Still trying to convince myself not to go down the sql DB route. Firebase pricing seems quite scary :)

Comment: > denormalizing data in such a way we can get the desired data in one query only 
This has got me thinking. I wonder if I even need an asset doc. Would that information be better against the file instead? That would mean ALOT of duplicate data though and if it needs updating, 1000's of updates. I think I just talked myself out of that :)

Comment: It all depends on your queries and how those queries are organized and triggered in your front-end.